# How to get the custom cell value using POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I have a excel sheet with the custom format value 24-09-2019. Some versions of excel sheet supports this format. If the dd-mm-yyyy format is present in the excel sheet the cell type is numeric.
If it is not present then the cell type is string. I need to get the value from the cell.

Comment: POI Cell interface has `public Date getDateCellValue()`

Comment: What did you try? If not, show one input sample and expected output sample.